# How can I stream audio to and from a caller from my nodejs app

Tags: json, audio, websocket, streaming, bidirectional

I'm writing a nodejs app that hosts a webhook for answering a call.  The basics are all working.  That is I can receive a call and provide a TWIML response.  However, I want to receive from the caller the audio stream and I also want to stream to the caller from an external source.

I'm using the twiml  response to setup this flow.

I've discovered the audio I receive from that socket is packaged in a JSON object.  I'm presuming the actual audio payload in that JSON object is base64 encoded.  So I can receive the caller audio and extract the payload and forward to my external source.  However, my understanding of the  sequence is that it provides bi-directional audio flow.  So my question is "How do I package the upstream audio packet I want to send to the caller"?

Do I have create a JSON object containing a similarly formatted payload?  Do I have to first start the upstreaming with the "start" message?  Or do I simply create "media" messages with the payload (base64 encoded)?

Here's what I'm currently doing:

1. Parse 'media' message from twilio and extract and decode payload of that message and send to external resource.
2. When I receive a G.711 ulaw encoded packet from my external resource, at the moment, I'm just sending it as is through the websocket.  I certainly don't hear anything at the far end however.

I do know my packets in fact do contain valid G.711 ulaw data from the xternal resource